# How to get intrinsic and extrinsic parameter matrix of my camera using Google ARCore

Tags: android-camera, augmented-reality, camera-calibration, opencv, python

I want to use Google ARCore to get the extrinsic and intrinsic parameter matrix of my mobile phone. So far, I only see documentation about getting the intrinsic parameter matrix but I don't see anything about getting the extrinsic parameter matrix. Is it possible to do that with Google ARCore?

Answer (score 2):

Thought I'd just update this with an answer I found a while ago:

```
Frame frame = arSceneView.getArFrame();

Camera camera = frame.getCamera();
CameraIntrinsics intrinsics = camera.getImageIntrinsics();
Camera coreCamera = frame.getCamera();
Pose camPose = coreCamera.getPose();
```